# Change view properties based on output of function angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-nativescript, angular2-changedetection

In my nativescript-angular app I display a list of data returned from the server. I show the results in a Listview. As each item is displayed in the list I run a function checkIfAdded(item). This function looks at each data item and for each item computes an "isAdded" boolean property for each item and returns either true or false for each item. Based on the result of this function I want to modify 3 properties for the button being displayed as follows:
1. I want to append a CSS class to the button
2. I want to change the displayed text of the button 
3. I want to change the function that is executed by the button.

Currently I am doing this as shown in the code below:

```
  <ListView row="2" *ngIf="searchItemsReturned" [items]="this.searchResults" class="list-group m-x-10" [itemTemplateSelector]="templateSelector">

//********* Template Type 1 **********          
<ng-template nsTemplateKey="type1" let-item="item">
   <StackLayout (tap)="onFeedItemSelect(item)">
       <Label [text] = item.name></Label>
       <Button [ngClass]="{'remove-button': checkIfAdded(item)}" 
            class="btn-highlight btn-add m-y-1 m-r-4" row="0" 
           [text]="checkIfAdded(item) ? 'Remove' : 'Add'" 
           (tap)="checkIfAdded(item) ? removeFromList(item): addToList(item)">
       </Button>
 </StackLayout>
```

While this way works in the code, I am calling the same a function in the view property binding and calling the same function thrice!!. This is also seems to be causing change detection to run multiple times each time i trigger a change, for example by tapping the button. Is there a better way to bind the 3 properties for the buttons that I show below each item in the list view. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Compute the `isAdded` property when you load the data. Then in your html just use that property instead of calling the function everytime:

```
//********* Template Type 1 **********          
<ng-template nsTemplateKey="type1" let-item="item">
   <StackLayout (tap)="onFeedItemSelect(item)">
       <Label [text] = item.name></Label>
       <Button [ngClass]="{'remove-button': item.isAdded}" 
        class="btn-highlight btn-add m-y-1 m-r-4" row="0" 
       [text]=" item.isAdded ? 'Remove' : 'Add'" 
       (tap)="  item.isAdded ? removeFromList(item): addToList(item)">
       </Button>
 </StackLayout>
```